# Error with Spring cloud contract with spring boot 1.5.x

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract, springrunner

I am trying to implement the Spring Cloud contract for the Spring boot application which is on 1.5.X.

I have added the below dependencies:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <packageWithBaseClasses>com.example</packageWithBaseClasses>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-verifier</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
           <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.2</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.2</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>

<dependencies>
    <!-- all dependencies -->
    <!-- you can exclude rest-assured from spring-cloud-contract-verifier -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
       <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.2</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.2</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have created my base class as below:

BaseClass.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) 
@SpringBootTest(classes=MySpringBootApplication.class)
public abstract class BaseClass {
  @Autowired
  MyController myController;

  //Mock Dependencies
  RestAssuredMockMVC.standaloneSetup(myController)
}
```

I can see that the tests are generating by spring contract as expected (based on yml contract) and my build is failing with below Error:

```
    java.lang.noclassdeffounderror org/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/binder
       at org.springframework.cloud.function.compiler.config.FunctionProxyApplicationListener.bind(FunctionProxyApplicationListener.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.compiler.config.FunctionProxyApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(FunctionProxyApplicationListener.java:87)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.compiler.config.FunctionProxyApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(FunctionProxyApplicationListener.java:48)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster:165)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster:139)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster:122)
.......
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a version of spring cloud contract that is incompatible with that version of spring boot. That's why you get the class not found exception

Comment: After using the ${spring-cloud-contract.version} as 1.2.7 I resolve the issue and able to run the test.

Now I am seeing 404 status instead of 200. The application is jersey based Rest application I am assuming it is because of this Jersey-based REst.

Can you please help me if there is a good example with Jersey based REst in SpringBoot 1.5.x or if there is a solution to resolve this issue.
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-verifier</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: This is an ancient version of boot and contract. Please upgrade. Here you have an example for jaxrs with contract 2.2.x https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/producer_jaxrs